# Android Jetpack Compose keyboard not close

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

Compose keyboard not close when scrolling

[everything is okey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RACrI.png)

[I'm scrolling but keyboard not close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhmtJ.png)

how can i solve this?

thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want hide the keyboard on scroll, you need to hide the on the scroll action of your nestedScrollConnection

```
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
object : NestedScrollConnection {
    override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source:NestedScrollSource): Offset {
        val delta = available.y
        keyboardController?.hide()
        return Offset.Zero
      }
   }
}  

Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)) {
      LazyColumn(){
           // Here your list itens
      }
}
```

Comment: It works but there is a lag issue because it is always triggered

Comment: also when i open the keyboard it is triggered because the scroll state changes and the keyboard closes

Comment: Instead lazyListState can you use NestedScrollConnection.

Comment: I change the awnser to NestedScrollConnection.

Comment: While this works, we can't open the keyboard when the scroll is "fling". My solution add a bool shouldBlock. In onPreFling, it is set to true, in onPostFling it is set to false. And we only hide the keyboard in onPreScroll if shouldBlock is false